# In symfony 1.4, how can I fetch data from a text file in the 'new template' page?

Tags: php, forms, symfony-1.4

I want to read a text file in the 'new template' of a module, so I can retrieve a number in that file, and give it as a field at the moment of saving that register. 
As an example, in the form I have this fields:

```
name:
description:
number:
```

The number field is in the text file, and I want to retrieve it before I press the "Save" button.
How could I do that?
Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can read the file before pressing the Save button. But, you could upload the file to the server and after that process the file uploaded to save the number.